# How to implement execute command inside for loop - postgres, dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dbeaver

I am new to postgres. I need to create a function that will take a list of all the tables in the database whose names are stored in one table and then delete the records of all the tables that are older than x days and have a certain row_status. Some tables do not have a row_status column.
I get an error when I try to save a written function in dbeaver -> **ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"**

```
create function delete_old_records1(day1 int, row_status1 character default null, row_status2 character default null)
returns void 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    c all_tables1%rowtype; 
begin
    
    
            for c in select * from all_tables1 loop 
                if exists(SELECT column_name FROM  information_schema.columns 
                WHERE  table_schema = 'yard_kondor' AND  table_name =c.table_name AND  column_name = 'row_status') then 
                    execute 'delete from '||c.table_name||' where row_create_datetime>current_date-day1+1 and 
                    row_status in (coalesce(row_status1,''P''), row_status2)'; 
                else 
                    execute 'delete from '||c.table_name||' where row_create_datetime>current_date-day1+1'; 
                    raise notice 'Table '||c.table_name||' does not have row_status column'; 
                end if; 
            end loop;       
        return; 
    commit;
end; 
$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is this line:

```
raise notice 'Table '||c.table_name||' does not have row_status column';
```

That [should be](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE):

```
raise notice 'Table % does not have row_status column', c.table_name;
```

However, your function could be improved a bit. In general it is highly recommended to use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to generate dynamic SQL to properly deal with identifiers. You also can't `commit` in a function. If you really need that, use a procedure.

```
create function delete_old_records1(day1 int, row_status1 character default null, row_status2 character default null)
returns void 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    c all_tables1%rowtype; 
begin
  for c in select * from all_tables1 
  loop 
    if exists (SELECT column_name FROM  information_schema.columns 
               WHERE table_schema = 'yard_kondor' 
                 AND table_name = c.table_name 
                 AND column_name = 'row_status') then 
      execute format('delete from %I 
                      where row_create_datetime > current_date - %J + 1 
                      and row_status in (coalesce(row_status1,%L), row_status2)', c.table_name, day1, 'P'); 
    else 
      execute format('delete from %I where row_create_datetime > current_date - day1 + 1', c.table_name); 
      raise notice 'Table % does not have row_status column', c.table_name; 
    end if; 
  end loop;       
  return; 
  -- you can't commit in a function
end; 
$$
```

Comment: Now I'm able to save function, but currently I have a problem with running the function.

I started the function with:

DO $$ BEGIN
    PERFORM "delete_old_records1"(31,'P','N');
END $$;
I started script with ALT+X (also tried select delete_old_records1(31,'P','N');) and have this error:

SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "day1" does not exist Where: PL/pgSQL function delete_old_records1(integer,character,character) line 11 at EXECUTE statement SQL statement "SELECT "delete_old_records1"(31,'P','N')" PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 2 at PERFORM

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. Now I'm able to save function, but currently I have a problem with running the function.

I started the function with:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    PERFORM "delete_old_records1"(31,'P','N');
END $$;
```

I started script with ALT+X (also tried `select delete_old_records1(31,'P','N');`) and have this error:

SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "day1" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function delete_old_records1(integer,character,character) line 11 at EXECUTE statement
SQL statement "SELECT "delete_old_records1"(31,'P','N')"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 2 at PERFORM